# Suppress cookie warnings

Tags: macos, safari, cookies

Cookie warnings (I think coming from EU directives) are becoming more common and more annoying. Cookies are not blocked in Safari (12.1.2) preferences. AdBockPlus (2.06) is also installed, which does a good job of suppressing unwanted ads. The iMac is running 12.14.6, and I'm located in the US.

A little searching indicates I might enable Prebake to suppress these warnings. The [Prebake page](http://prebake.eu) contains [a link](http://abp:subscribe?location=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.github.com%2Fliamja%2FPrebake%2Fmaster%2Fobtrusive.txt&title=Prebake%20-%20Block%20obtrusive%20EU%20cookie%20notices) to add Prebake's filter list to the Safari filter list, but Safari won't load the linked page, not surprising given the link's formatting. Deleting the characters before "https" doesn't help. Neither Safari preferences, the ABP icon in Safari, nor the ABP Control Panel (2.0.6) show or suggest how to access the Safari filter list.

I'm not a programmer, but only a dilletante amateur. Is there a way to add this filter to the Safari filter list? Alternatively, is there another way to suppress these repeated cookie warnings?

Comment: [How can I block email signup overlays or javascript popups in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354610/how-can-i-block-email-signup-overlays-or-javascript-popups-in-safari) regarding your *alternate* mention. Not a duplicate, just related.

Comment: The data is in the format for "[Adblock Plus 1.1]". https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liamja/Prebake/master/obtrusive.txt  You would need to run adblock plus or modify the data to something safari supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## uBlock-Safari

You could replace AdBlockPlus with the open source Safari extension [uBlock-Safari](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari) and [import the filter list](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dashboard:-Filter-lists).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin

See [FilterLists](https://filterlists.com) for a good source of filters - including cookie notification specific lists.

Comment: Thanks ,@Graham Miln. I've give them a try.

Comment: Turns out that's pretty effective, thanks. I upvoted and checked your answer.