# Turning off "Use Google Account to sign in..."

Tags: safari, google

I googled up a random topic this morning and got this:

[image]

Which is really odd, because I long ago did this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to turn this crap off in Safari once and for all?

macOS 12.6.5, Safari 16.5.

Comment: It's not a Safari issue, it's a Google issue. You must have enabled it at some point in your own Google account - which is also where the switch is. https://www.howtogeek.com/735152/how-to-turn-off-the-sign-in-with-google-prompt-on-websites/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Safari is not Apple software? And as I CLEARLY demonstrated in the post above, I have it turned off.

Comment: Did you clear cookies etc. for Google and GeeksforGeeks, and restart your browser afterwards?

Comment: This is also a dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354616/119271

Comment: @nohillside - I have never visited G4G before, and Safari has been rebooted several times (power cycles actually) since turning this option off.

Comment: @Allan - it is not a dup. The popup is not part of the page I visited, it appears only when I land on the page from Google search (in this case "X.25 vs frame relay"). It appears to be something Google is injecting, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Google is not “injecting” it.  They (G4G) are using [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) to allow users to login

Comment: I can't reproduce this here, searching for "X.25 vs frame relay" and then clicking on the G4G link on the top doesn't show the pop-up. Just to be sure: did you remove any google-related cookies etc., restart Safari and immediately try it again?

Comment: I was able to replicate this on Sari, Firefox, and Edge on both macOS and iOS.  It is, BTW, the exact same modal/API  that appears on SE. (I also don’t use Google to sign into anything)

Comment: @nohillside - yes it keeps coming up after clearing all cookies and restarting. And the option is turned off in Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is a Google issue

Sites, including Stack Exchange use the Google Identity Services API to provide authentication services to it’s users. Specifically, this appears to be [Google One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features).

[image]

[image]

<sup>Images sourced from Google Identity Services API documentation</sup>

The aforementioned link provides code samples to implement this functionality and guidelines for displaying the modals.
Interestingly enough, the nomenclature for this modal is called “warm welcome.”

This is very similar to the existing question [Stop Gmail pop-up ad "Google recommends using Chrome"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454179/119271).

#### Google Opt Out

Per Google’s own guidelines pertaining to One Tap, under the heading [Understand the One Tap user experience](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features), they state:

> Users can opt out of One Tap if they disable the Google Account sign-in prompts flag in the Apps with access to your account page. The opted-out sessions aren't shown in One Tap. If all Google sessions are opted out, One Tap doesn't display.

I can tell you that I have opted out of everything in my Google account and I still get this modal quite often. This is either an issue with Google’s API itself or the websites’ implementation of it.  Either way, it’s not an issue with Safari or macOS/iOS/iPadOS.

Comment: So no solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Safari Extension to block these, called Hush. I only just installed it, but verified that I don't see it on Reddit in an incognito window in Safari. I reloaded the page without content blockers, and see the Google sign in prompt again. So it seems to be working for me.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hush-nag-blocker/id1544743900

Comment: Are you affiliated with the developer in any way?